# ?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq 'user@gmail.com') is returning error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I need to find a user in my B2C with `issuerAssignedId` equal with specific email.

My query is like this:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId  eq 'thedivision5623u12@gmail.com')`

However, I get the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Issuer is not set in the query. Issuer issuer, IssuerUserId: issuerUserId",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2023-05-12T01:38:42",
      "request-id": "9961ba9b-4027-45ab-bdf7-024ab80c634b",
      "client-request-id": "9961ba9b-4027-45ab-bdf7-024ab80c634b"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I fix the query above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When filtering on the `identities` property for an `issuerAssignedId`, you must supply both `issuer` and `issuerAssignedId`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId  eq 'thedivision5623u12@gmail.com' and c/issuer eq 'My B2C tenant')
```

Resources:

[Object identity - filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0#filtering)

[Filter example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following
With the following query

GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId  eq 'tddd@gmail.com'`
Got the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Issuer is not set in the query. Issuer issuer, IssuerUserId: issuerUserId",
        
    }
}
```

[image]
Try the following query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId  eq 'kxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com' and c/issuer eq 'kxxxb2c.onmicrosoft.com')
```

It runs without any error:

[image]

But check the following to see the known issues:

[User query $filter ignores identities/issuer - MS Graph API and Azure B2C - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/826199/user-query-filter-ignores-identities-issuer-ms-gra)